# Django How to Post comment on only one List item

Tags: html, css, django

I am trying to create django commerce app I am little bit stuck on a thing

When I post comment via form I created

```
<form action="{% url 'comment' list_id.id %}" method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <textarea name="comment" class="inp-cmt" rows="3"></textarea>
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
```

the comment is posted but it post on all of my list page I wanted only on the page where comment is posted

my comment section

```
{% if allcomments %}
        <h1>Comments</h1>
        <div class="card-cmt">
          {%for com in allcomments%}
            <li style="list-style: none;">
                <footer class="post-info">
                <span>{{com.user}}</span>
                <p>{{com.text}}</p>
            </footer>
            </li>
         {% endfor %}
     </div>
{% endif %}
```

my urls

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.index, name="index"),
    path("login", views.login_view, name="login"),
    path("logout", views.logout_view, name="logout"),
    path("register", views.register, name="register"),
    path("newlist", views.create_listing, name="new_list"),
    path("item", views.add_item, name="new_item"),
    path("listing/<int:list_id>", views.listing, name="listing"),
    path("delete/<int:item_id>", views.delete_list, name="delete"),
    path("comment/<int:list_id>", views.comments, name="comment")
]
```

my views for comment and listing

```
def comments(request, list_id): 
    coms = Comments()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        coms.user = request.user.username
        coms.text = request.POST.get('comment')
        coms.listid = list_id
        coms.save()
        return redirect('listing', list_id)
    else :
        return redirect('index')    

def listing(request, list_id):
    list_item = Listing.objects.get(id=list_id)
    return render(request, "auctions/listing.html",{
        "list_id" : list_item,
        "allcomments" : Comments.objects.all()
    })
```

models

```
class Listing(models.Model):
    owner = models.CharField(max_length =64,default="N/A")
    productname = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=999, default="test")
    date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    link = models.CharField(max_length=200, default="test1")

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.owner} {self.productname} {self.price} {self.date} {self.description} {self.link}"


class Comments(models.Model):
    user = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    text = models.TextField()
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    listid = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.user} {self.text} {self.date} {self.listid}"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're returning all comments on every listing when you do `"allcomments" : Comments.objects.all()`
The problem is in your `listing` function. Try this instead:

```
def listing(request, list_id):
    list_item = Listing.objects.get(id=list_id)
    return render(request, "auctions/listing.html",{
        "list_id" : list_item,
        "allcomments" : Comments.objects.filter(listid=list_id)
    })
```

Notice the change - from `"allcomments" : Comments.objects.all()` to `"allcomments" : Comments.objects.filter(listid=list_id)`

Also, your implementation for `class Comments` and `class Listing` could be a bit better. Have you ever come across something called a ForeignKey? It will be a lot more efficient to use that. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey

Comment: Thanks for your reply, It worked  and I will try to use Foriegn Key as I am new to django

Comment: Haha dont mention it. What you did when you didn't know about foreignkeys is exactly what I did in my first project lol so I thought I'd just point it out